how to make driven scene properties update in the UI?
I am writing an addon that has a property which needs the #frame driver, but when I play the timeline automatically (space key to play), the value doesn't update in the UI. However, when you drag the timeline, it is live updating. Also, when you click non blank space (e.g., select/deselect an object) in the scene, it updates too, no updating when you click blank space anyway.

I searched here and google, there are similar questions, but none of them directly related to my scenarios. Any help would be appreciated.
I have a minimum example code of the addon to test, you can test by inputing #frame to the Frame or Count input field.
'''
The driven properties don't update on UI mini example
'''

bl_info = {
    "name": "custom property",
    "description": "Test properties",
    "author": "Jack",
    "version": (1, 0, 0),
    "blender": (4, 1, 0),
    "location": "3D View > Sidebar > Audio Visualizer",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "category": "3D View",
    }

import importlib
import sys
import bpy

class CustomPropertyGroup(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    frame: bpy.props.IntProperty(
        name = "Frame",
        default = 0,
        description = ("Frame")
    )

    count: bpy.props.IntProperty(
        name = "Count",
        default = 20,
        min = 1,
        description = ("The number of bins")
    )

class CustomPropertyPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = "CUSTOMNODE_PT_Panel"
    bl_label = "Custom property"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Custom Property"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.use_property_split = True
        layout.use_property_decorate = True # True for value animatable.

        scene = context.scene
        propData = context.scene.custom_nodes

        # render setting
        layout.label(text="Custom Property")
        layout.prop(propData,"frame",text="Frame")
        layout.prop(propData,"count",text="Count")


def register():
    # properties
    bpy.utils.register_class(CustomPropertyGroup)
    bpy.types.Scene.custom_nodes = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=CustomPropertyGroup)

    # ui
    bpy.utils.register_class(CustomPropertyPanel)


def unregister():
    # properties
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(CustomPropertyGroup)

    # ui
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(CustomPropertyPanel)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()


Why should the displayed number update during playback? What do you want to do with it?

Because I need use the value as the playback going, I want to use the value to calculate other values. Another thing I found that when the mouse is in the UI region during the playback, the value is also live updating. For your questioning why the displayed number should update with its current status, I don't understand why it shouldn't reflect its value in real-time.
